# Can't flatten output from Keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, shap

I have the below model built with Keras, and I am training it using StratifiedKFold. Training works nice, performance is good. Now I am trying to explain the model predictions using the SHAP library. My dateset shape is (107012, 67) and the below is the the code I wrote that encodes my data, trains and makes predictions. `original_X` is the variable I am reading my data in using Pandas. Most of my data is categorical and only one column contains continuous values.

```
ohe = OneHotEncoder()
mms = MinMaxScaler()

ct = make_column_transformer(
    (ohe, categorical_columns_encode),
    (mms, numerical_columns_encode),
    remainder='passthrough')

ct.fit(original_X.astype(str))
X = ct.transform(original_X.astype(str))
print(X.shape) # Shape of the encoded value (107012, 47726)

recall = Recall(name="recall")
prec = Precision(name="precision")
ba = BinaryAccuracy()

def get_model():
  network = Sequential()
  network.add(Input(shape=X_1.shape))
  network.add(Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
  network.add(Dropout(0.5))
  network.add(Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
  network.add(Dropout(0.5))
  network.add(Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
  # network.add(Flatten())
  network.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

  network.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
              metrics=[recall, prec, ba])
  return network

classifier = KerasClassifier(build_fn=get_model)
kfold = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=3, n_repeats=3, random_state=42)

callback = EarlyStopping(
    monitor='val_recall',
    min_delta=0,
    patience=0,
    verbose=1,
    mode="auto",
    baseline=None,
    restore_best_weights=True
)

epochs_per_fold = []

for train, validation in kfold.split(X_1, y_1):
  X_train, X_validation = X_1[train], X_1[validation]
  y_train, y_validation = y_1[train], y_1[validation]

  # Printing the distribution of classes in the training set
  counter = Counter(y_train)
  print("Number of class distributions of the training set ", counter)
  print("Minority case percentage of the training set ", counter[1] / (counter[0] + counter[1]))
  
  # Training our model and saving the history of the training
  history = classifier.fit(
    x=X_train,
    y=y_train,
    verbose=1,
    epochs=30,
    shuffle=True,
    callbacks=[callback],
    class_weight={0: 1.0, 1: 3.0},
    validation_data=(X_validation, y_validation))

  # predict classes for our validation set in order to manually verify the metrics
  yhat_classes = (classifier.predict(X_validation) > 0.5).astype("int32")

  TP = 0
  FP = 0
  TN = 0
  FN = 0

  # Record our preditions for the confusion matrix for manually verifying our metrics
  for p,t in zip(y_validation, yhat_classes):
    if p == 1 and t == 1:
      TP += 1
    elif p == 0 and t == 1:
      FP += 1
    elif p == 1 and t == 0:
      FN += 1
    elif p == 0 and t == 0:
      TN += 1
  
  print("\n")
  print(" "*16, "T  F")
  print("Positive result ", TP, FP, )
  print("Negative result ", TN, FN, )
  print("\n")

  # Printing the built in classification report of our model
  print(classification_report(y_validation, yhat_classes))

  report_dict = classification_report(y_validation, yhat_classes, output_dict=True)

  # Record the average number of epochs of training
  epochs_per_fold.append(len(history.history['recall']))
  print(yhat_classes)
```

Here I am trying to use DeepExplainer from the Shap libeary to look inside my predictions.

```
# we use the first 100 training examples as our background dataset to integrate over
background = X_2[np.random.choice(X_2.shape[0], 100, replace=False)]

explainer = shap.DeepExplainer(get_model(), background)
```

When the code reaches the explainer declaration the below error is thrown.

```
Your TensorFlow version is newer than 2.4.0 and so graph support has been removed in eager mode. See PR #1483 for discussion.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-113-d24b2d1e3b91> in <module>()
----> 1 explainer = shap.DeepExplainer(get_model(), background)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/shap/explainers/_deep/deep_tf.py in __init__(self, model, data, session, learning_phase_flags)
    100         self.model_output = _get_model_output(model)
    101         assert type(self.model_output) != list, "The model output to be explained must be a single tensor!"
--> 102         assert len(self.model_output.shape) < 3, "The model output must be a vector or a single value!"
    103         self.multi_output = True
    104         if len(self.model_output.shape) == 1:

AssertionError: The model output must be a vector or a single value!
```

My questions are:

1. How can I flatten the output of my model from within the `get_model` function?
2. Is there a better approach to explaining my predictions with Shap?

Let me know if I need to share any extra information on this.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `Flatten` layer after a `Dense` layer is causing the error. Observe, that the line which causes the error is,

```
assert len(self.model_output.shape) < 3, "The model output must be a vector or a single value!"
```

Considering a 2D input, the output of a `Dense` layer is `( None , units )`. So, if we have a `Dense( 32 )` layer and the batch size is set to 16, then the output of such a layer will be a tensor of shape `( 16 , 32 )`. The `Flatten` layer preserves the 0th axis ( i.e. the batch dimension ), and hence a tensor of shape `( 16 , 32 )` could be flattened further.

On the other hand, if you had a tensor of shape `( 16 , 32 , 3 )` ( for ex. output of a `Conv2D` layer with 3 filters ) then the output of the `Flatten` layer will be a tensor of shape `( 16 , 96 )`.

> Since you have 2D input, just remove the `Flatten` layer. If you were
> trying to reshape the output, use a `Reshape` layer instead.